# Sql Server Bulk insert via file separated with special charactors

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I have File to be imported into SQL Server table, I am importing that via BCP command via command line in C# when I pass Comma(,) as Separator in format file then it works fine, but when I try to pass Special char this  as separator then it fails and giving me below error.

> XML parsing: line 2, character 0, incorrect document syntax

*Note: due to some reasons Stackoverflow not showing my special character, Please copy format file into your text editor like notepad++ or something else.*

My format file as following for special char.

```
12.0
20
1       SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      2        Column1                                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      3        Column2                                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      0        XyzColumnToBypass                                           ""
4       SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      0        XyzColumnToBypass                                           ""
5       SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      0        XyzColumnToBypass                                           ""
6       SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      0        XyzColumnToBypass                                           ""
7       SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      0        XyzColumnToBypass                                           ""
8       SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      0        XyzColumnToBypass                                           ""
9       SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      0        XyzColumnToBypass                                           ""
10      SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      0        XyzColumnToBypass                                           ""
11      SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      0        XyzColumnToBypass                                           ""
12      SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      0        XyzColumnToBypass                                           ""
13      SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      7        Column4                                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
14      SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      6        Column5                                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
15      SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      5        Column6                                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
16      SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      0        XyzColumnToBypass                                           ""
17      SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      0        XyzColumnToBypass                                           ""
18      SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      0        XyzColumnToBypass                                           ""
19      SQLCHAR             0       0       ""      0        XyzColumnToBypass                                           ""
20      SQLCHAR             0       0       "\r\n"   0        XyzColumnToBypass                                           ""
```

I also tried via SQL server using below query but got the same error.

```
BULK INSERT mySqlServerTable   
FROM '\\machinexxx\Shared\BCP\TextfileToImport_SpecialChar.dat'
WITH(FORMATFILE = '\\machinexxx\Shared\BCP\formatfile.fmt')
```

I don't know why it accessing my non-XML format file as xml format file while my encoding for the format file is ASCII.

Comment: First, i copied your format file into notepad++ and no special character is showed. Second your question is not related to ssis

Comment: @Hadi you will find the file here. https://github.com/jenish1993/MyShares/blob/master/formatfile.fmt